# Why doesn't array.append print up?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider `a` to be an array

```
print(a.append(1))
```

Why doesn't this print `a`'s elements, it gives a message as `None`, whereas

```
print(a.index())
```

gives the desired result?

Comment: Also that's a *list*, and DON'T SHOUT.

Answer (score 1):

> Why doesn't this print a's elements

Why should it? append is meant to modify the list in-place. When you `print(a.append(1))`, you are appending 1 to a, and printing the result of calling append (the object returned by the append method), which is None.